# using Standard Values Instead of constant in Autolayout IOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have just started learning IOS Development so my knowledge to it is very little.

I am building my layout for my app. I need my app to run on all devices . I have read somewhere that you should never use a constant magic number when creating constraints and always use standard values. I want to support my app for all resolutions

whenever I set standard value it's '0' so does this means that I have to play with multiplier values to have similar spacing

And kindly let me know when we can use constant value and when we have to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the times you need to space the views evenly in the screen . This makes the view look similar on all devices (like on a bigger screen it should be equivalent to scaled version of how it looks on a smaller screen).

For Eg. If you need to space 3 views horizontally and equally on a view. If you set the height/width of the buttons to a magic number, say 100 pixels. The 3 subviews would look relatively smaller on a iPhone6+ screen than say on a iPhone5 screen.
This is when you use multipliers. Like height/width of buttons =  0.2 of superview.

On the other hand you need to use magic numbers in some cases.

For Eg. You are creating a canvas on the screen in which the user will draw with a menu panel on the left. You know the menu panel fits in say a 50 pixel strip on the left. So if you set the size of the menu panel by a multiplier, then the menu panel will become larger on bigger screens. This would somewhat nullify the advantage of having a bigger screen to draw. 
This is when you use magic numbers as you know the menu panel needed to be no larger than 50 pixels.

(Note: never use magic numbers directly. Create constants like k_menu_bar_height = 50. Then use this constant wherever you need. This is much more readable and helps in the long run from a maintenance point of view)

Comment: The last paragraph is up to discuss - why would you use myCustomDoubleValueWidthForMyCustomComponentWhichIsNeverGonnaBeUsedOnceMore instead of 50.0? Where exactly it is more readable?)

Comment: Agreed @Stas. 
I would personally be fine with using 50.0 directly as long as its purely view code and the occurrence is not more than once. 
Although I have worked with Architects who insist on creating constants for magic numbers irrespective of where or how many times they are used.